# Relative size of symbols

Tags: symbols, text

[image]This is perhaps a typography question rather than a LaTeX one.  I'm using playing card symbols from Book Antiqua and the heart symbol feels too big to me (subjective, I know).  So I rescale it and that looks OK in the first text line of the MWE.

But then I use the symbols again when they are very close together and the sizes look wrong to my eye.  What I think is happening is that the relatively large numbers and brackets change the size perception.

I could make the brackets smaller but I wonder how other people would address this issue.  Or if they even see it as an issue :-)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[HTML, hyperref, x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{relsize}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\newfontface{\BCards}{Book Antiqua}

\NewDocumentCommand{\BCs}{}{{\BCards\char"2663}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\BDs}{}{{\color{red}\BCards\char"2666}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\BHs}{}{{\relscale{0.9}\color{red}\BCards\char"2665}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\BSs}{}{{\BCards\char"2660}}


\begin{document}


In sequence 1\BCs{}--1\BDs{}--1\BHs{}--1\BSs{}


\begin{tabular}{@{} *{3}{l}}
2NT     &                       &\\
        &Pass                   &0--4 HL ;\\
        &3\BCs{}                &4+ HL, Stayman Puppet ;\\
        &3\BDs{}(\BHs{})        &4+ HL, Texas M ;\\
        &3\BSs{}(4\BCs{})       &4+ HL, Texas m ;\\
        &4\BHs{}(\BSs{})        &9+ HL, two suiter ;\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might have a better chance at getting answers if you post an image showing the output. I don't have the BookAntiqua font, so I can't compile your MWE.

Comment: Very subjective. I'd not use `relsize` in this case; try with `\NewDocumentCommand{\BHs}{}{\scalebox{0.95}{\color{red}\BCards\char"2665}}` (with `\usepackage{graphicx}`). [Output (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPm8u.png)

Comment: @egreg Yes, that looks better to me.  How did you arrive at that?

Comment: @DLyons `\relscale` operates at discrete steps. You just want to remove the apparent overshooting of the heart suit (it's an optical illusion, mainly due to the bright red), not to reduce the font size to 10pt.

Comment: You may try `\color{red!91!blue}` with the two suits side by side at natural size; I believe that the overshooting illusion is much smaller.

Comment: That helps also.  I've reduced the bracket size and replaced one usage with U+0337 and now like Goldilocks it looks "just right".  At least to me!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has finded an optimal solution from the comments.